# Helm - how to manage customizations in external charts

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

so I am creating a system composed of different components that are installed via helm charts. Since I needed different customizations for each of the charts, I created my own separated repositories, copied the charts there and added customizations.

The question is: how do I conveniently upgrade the charts versions, while keeping the customizations?

For some of the components it was an easy task, since custom templates were moved to different folder and when upgrade is needed I simply replace old files with the new one.

The issue is that in some charts I needed to alter the original files directly, for example in the middle of a template adding necessary stuff. So, during the upgrade of such component I have to go through all files, compare them, remember what changes are mine and then update the whole repository. So yes, you guessed it - it's manual, inconvenient and error prune task.

I tried looking for good practices how to maintain such repositories, but I couldn't find any answers, so I'd be more than happy to take any advice.

Comment: I'm not sure I got what you're asking. If you forked the repositories which contains the original charts and added some customizations on those, why you don't just `install`/`upgrade` the charts from your repositories?

Comment: Let's say you have a chart with version 1.0.0, so I fork it, then modify template X, and then install it into my cluster. Some time later new version of the chart was introduced, namely 2.0.0, and I want to upgrade chart in my repo. If I want to do that it is manual work to go through all the files and merge it. Situation will be similar to resolving merge conflicts manually.

Comment: Ok got it now sorry. But I don't think you've any alternative other than merge them manually, what do you expect to be able to do? Once you fork and modify it their development diverges.

Comment: Yes, I was afraid someone, might say it. Nevertheless, since I believe it's a common use-case, I was hoping someone has a crafty way of doing that. Anyway, thank you for the input, it's a still valuable information to have for the future of the project.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it often happens that the Helm Chart repositories of an application aren't suitable for the environment in which you are going to install them.

I suggest modifying the templates following the patterns of how they were written and sending PRs to the application's GitHub repository.

Unless these are "reasonable" configurations, such as things that complicate the application for whatever reason, there's no other way than to do a "git diff" before downloading the updated repo.

Answer (score 1):

If your changes are very specific to your project and not something that can be merged into the original repo, or you have legal loopholes to jump through, you can fork  the original code and periodically sync up with the upstream.

The process is outlined here:
https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/working-with-forks/syncing-a-fork

Obviously you still have to resolve conflicts, but you can set up a CI pipeline to periodically sync and update your helm registry.